# Create Excel Templates In SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am creating a SSIS package that takes some values, loops through those values and dynamically creates Excel files with the values from the loop included in the file name.

I have created the variables to hold the file name and the query values and set the `ForEachLoop Container` to loop through it.

I'm currently stuck on creating a table template for the data to go into the Excel files. The code I'm using is the following inside an `Execute SQL Task`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Basic Cases` (
`Type of Case` LongText,
`Receipt` DateTime,
`Address` LongText,
`Postcode` LongText,
`Ref No` LongText,
`Value` Currency)
```

The code format was from this snippet here https://sqljourney.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/ssis-create-new-excel-file-dynamically-to-export-data/ and I've seen other examples of it in use but cannot get it to work. Have tried a number of permutations but the query fails to parse.

Any ideas?

I'm using a 32bit AccessRunTimeEngine so I can create the Excel templates.

Comment: Dynamically creating Excel files with names inside it is not the best way to do in SSIS. I would download  https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus  Then you can install their nuget package and use a C# console to do your work. Call your SQL Table inside your C# script and make it dynamically in console app. This dude shows your how: https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/create-excel-files-in-c-sharp -

Comment: I have to use SSIS as thats the re-mit. I found the answer in any case; the {CR}{LF} characters were causing the problems for some reason, as soon as I removed those, it worked for me. Adding the nuget package and involving C# was adding an unnecessary layer of complexity although I had seen similar solutions online. Thanks.